# App working only above Android 4.2

Tags: android, eclipse

I Have developed a simple Android App, But the problem is the app is only working on devices above android 4.2. Even if an AVD below 4.2 is running, Eclipse Console says- **No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD.**

Running the apk on a device force closes the app. The Manifest file is-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dodo.flames"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Result"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
    <activity android:name=".What"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
    <activity android:name=".HistoryPage"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
</application>
```

And Following are the libraries I have used

```
import java.util.Vector;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Have you changed `minSdkVersion` recently?

Comment: The problem was there from the beginning before I did any change. Then I tried changing a couple of times.

Comment: @Sucho post the logcat.

Comment: I am not getting any logcat entries when I am trying to run In devices below 4.2 as the app is not even starting. But Above 4.2 It works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that you've configured the AVD properly for below 4.2? (Are the lower API levels installed in the SDK?)

Comment: Yes, I have tried on real devices to, which leads to force close of app. Other Apps run flawlessly on AVDs below 4.2. I even tried making a new project and copied the xml files and copy-pasting the contents of class files in new class files of the new project. No Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check your SDK manager whether you have API level 8 installed. I guess you've installed higher levels only.

Comment: Didn't help! Problem Persists!